# how to get output of ls command to an array in c++

Tags: c++, linux, arrays, ls, output

Is there a way to run the linux command ls, from c++, and get all the outputs stored in one array, in c++?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c/479103 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on actually running `ls`, you can use `popen` to launch the process and read the output:

```
FILE *proc = popen("/bin/ls -al","r");
char buf[1024];
while ( !feof(proc) && fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),proc) )
{
    printf("Line read: %s",buf);
}
```

But you could probably better be reading the directory contents and file info yourself, using `opendir` and `readdir`.